# module initialization error: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_dotenv'

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Line 14 of .py file:

dotenv.read_dotenv()

Yields this error:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_dotenv'

(I'm a noob in training... Appreciate the help)

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Like what should the output be?  The module you have imported does not contain that function, that is the problem.  I am wondering if there is a better way to do what this function is expected to do.

Comment: I'm trying to create an aws lambda function. I installed all the required pip modules (dotenv being 1 of them). I am basically taking a public github tutorial and trying to use it for my own personal use.https://github.com/shadowfax-chc/alexa-plex-py

Comment: What tutorial?  Can you share a link?

Comment: https://github.com/shadowfax-chc/alexa-plex-py

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: My aplexa.py file?

Comment: no the one you wrote

Comment: Right now I'm using the aplex.py from the github. I'm trying to get it to execute in Python and aws lambda before creating the Alexa skill. I've been able to clear errors and move on all day today but this error has me completely stumped

Comment: Once I get it working I can change the variables to my own in the .env file

Comment: Is the line saying read file dotenv? Or is it looking for a file named read_dotenv?

Comment: You have a module `dotenv`, it is looking for a function in that module called `read_dotenv`, found [here](https://github.com/shadowfax-chc/alexa-plex-py/blob/2cf3833e75a5a9a18bd1b998b5a37bc0de6c899a/aplexa.py#LC16):

Comment: I just read something that said read_dotenv is being deprecated and being replaced with load_dotenv. Can I make this change?

Answer (score 19):

I had the problem with Django, what solved it for me is uninstalling dotenv and python-dotenv and then reinstall django-dotenv

```
pip uninstall dotenv
pip uninstall python-dotenv
pip install django-dotenv
```

Comment: Ah this was my mistake, installed the wrong package :)